# Custom ld-linux.so for subprocesses

Tags: shared-libraries, ld, glibc, dynamic-linking, libc

I am running a program with a set of custom libraries as follows:

```
/path/to/my/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /path/to/my/libs /path/to/my/executable
```

This works great for most of the programs I am trying to run, but it doesn't seem to work for one which spawns subprocesses. I'm pretty sure the subprocesses are being spawned with standard glibc `execve`. The subprocess is failing with a library error which appears to be caused by it not being executed properly. The program works with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to the a directory containing all of the libraries except libc in a distroless Docker container, so I am pretty sure that I have all of the libraries correct.

I also tried using both setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and invoking with `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, but that doesn't work either.

I think the problem is that the subprocess is reverting to the system `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

For context, I have a binary (and a second binary which the first invokes as a subprocess) that I didn't build that I want to run on various systems with different sets of dynamic libraries installed. Using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and providing all libraries except libc works for most environments, except for one with a really old glibc installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the problem is that the subprocess is reverting to the system /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2.

That is what one *should expect* to happen if the `execve` argument is `/path/to/subprocess` or `subprocess`.

If you want the subprocess to use explicit loader invocation `/path/to/my/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /path/to/my/libs /path/to/subprocess`, then you *must* arrange for `execve` arguments to be *exactly that*.

This is why using `patchelf` or other solutions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) is generally a better approach.